# WordPress posting HTML and CSS code

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In WordPress, am creating a new post. In the HTML section of the post am using the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {color:red;}
h1 {color:#00ff00;}
p.ex {color:rgb(0,0,255);}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<p>This is an ordinary paragraph. Notice that this text is red. The default text-color for a page is defined in the body selector.</p>
<p class="ex">This is a paragraph with class="ex". This text is blue.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The text h1 font size is not coming that much, please help with this.

Comment: You're adding `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags to your post?  Don't.  WordPress will handle all that, just put in the code for your post.  Also, can you clarify what the problem is?  "Size not coming that much" is not a clear statement of problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `<style>` section, add:

`h1, p {font-size:14px}` or whatever size you want to use.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong or your sample code does not match reality.

Comment: sir..am trying this one..have a look   http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_color

Comment: Assuming you correctly placed that into the `<style>` element, the only reason this would not work is if the wordpress theme you are using assigns a size to the `<h1>` element outside of the CSS you control. We would need to see the actual HTML being generated before we could debug that issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, if your writting into the POST (html) you should not use the  and so into the field.

Your post should only looks like this

```
 <style type="text/css">
body {color:red;}
h1 {color:#00ff00;}
p.ex {color:rgb(0,0,255);}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<p>This is an ordinary paragraph. Notice that this text is red. The default text-color for a page is defined in the body selector.</p>
<p class="ex">This is a paragraph with class="ex". This text is blue.</p>
```

But the fact is that why your not placing your css into a specific CSS file? In the root of your theme, your should have a default style.css to use.

Also, can you check that your using a reset.css or something like this that would overwrite what your entered into the field?